# Unexpected token in JSON

Tags: c#, angularjs, json

I have checked JSON string response of  at
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it says that JSON string is valid.

Following is the function which I have used to serialize data to JSON string:

```
private string getJSONData()
{
    obj_userSession = new UserSession();
    DataTable dtRender = null;
    DataView dvRender = null;

    obj_userSession = new UserSession();
    if (obj_userSession.LoginData != null && obj_userSession.EmailsDetails != null)
    {
        dvRender = new DataView(obj_userSession.EmailsDetails);
        dtRender = dvRender.ToTable("EmailsDetails", false, "MessageDate", "SentFrom", "MessageBody", "SentTo", "MLSNumber");
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtRender);
    }
    return "";
}
```

And here is the response from above function as JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "MessageDate": "2016-04-04T05:42:38.273",
        "SentFrom": "Site Team",
        "MessageBody": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n\t<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n\t\t.c0 { font-family:'Arial';font-size:10.5pt; }\r\n\t\t.c1 { margin-left:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-right:0pt;margin-bottom:7.5pt; }\r\n\t</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body class=\"c0\">\r\n<p class=\"c1\">Hi Joe, </p>\r\n<p class=\"c1\">Testing Site</p>\r\n<p class=\"c1\">--James</p>\r\n<p class=\"c1\"></p>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
        "SentTo": "James",
        "Number": ""
    }
]
```

We does not getting any error in code but result not displayed in browser. And gets above mention error in developer tools in browser.

If I removed `MessageBody` from function `getJSONData` to avoid it from serializing and remove binding code from design page for `MessageBody` then it works fine.

What character I have to escape from `MessageBody` and how to do it?

**Edit**
This is AngularJS controller function which I have used to get data from:

```
$scope.browseListing = function (strURL) {
    $scope.getURL(strURL);
    $http.post($scope.URL)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.Data = response.data;
                if ($scope.IsMap)
                    $scope.LoadMapData();
                if ($scope.IsDetails)
                    $scope.buildReportURL($scope.Data[0].ListingID);

            }, function (response) {
                $log.info(response);
            });
};
```

And this is the html binding:

```
<tr ng-repeat="listing in Data">
    <td colspan="6">
        <table class="tblListingOuter">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20%;">
                </th>
                <th style="width:80%;">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Date: </b>{{ listing.MessageDate }}</td>
                <td><b>Message: </b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Sent By: </b>{{ listing.SentFrom }}</td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                    <pre contenteditable="true" ng-bind-html="listing.MessageBody | unsafe"></pre>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Sent To: </b>{{ listing.SentTo }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>MLSNO: </b>{{ listing.MLSNumber }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your Json is invalid, check it on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Did you intend to have a semicolon at the end of your JSON?

Comment: yeah if you remove that it passes the lint test

Comment: @HomrZodyssey, that semicolon added by mistake while posting question..

Comment: Can you show the code you use to read the JSON?

Comment: @HomrZodyssey, I am using AngularJS to bind that response to html...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Newtonsoft `JsonSerializerSettings` you have property `StringEscapeHandling` which specifies how strings are escaped when writing json. code below may work for you

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtRender, settings)
```

acceptable values for this property listed in documentation here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm

you may try other flags to get it working

Comment: my fault, fixed code. that happends when toy write something from your head without ide opened

Comment: and with other options? (EscapeHtml ? )

Comment: that's working but by making slight changes. I have used `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml` instead of  `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii` and its starts to work...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but you may try double-escaping the escaped characters in the MessageBody, like this:

```
[
    {
        "MessageDate": "2016-04-04T05:42:38.273",
        "SentFrom": "Site Team",
        "MessageBody": "<html>\\r\\n<head>\\r\\n\\t<style type=\\"text/css\\">\\r\\n\\t\\t.c0 { font-family:'Arial';font-size:10.5pt; }\\r\\n\\t\\t.c1 { margin-left:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-right:0pt;margin-bottom:7.5pt; }\\r\\n\\t</style>\\r\\n</head>\\r\\n<body class=\\"c0\\">\\r\\n<p class=\\"c1\"\>Hi Joe, </p>\\r\\n<p class=\\"c1\\">Testing Site</p>\\r\\n<p class=\\"c1\\">--James</p>\\r\\n<p class=\\"c1\\"></p>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n",
        "SentTo": "James",
        "Number": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: I have added that using str.Replace("\\","\\\\") but not working. How to do that.?

Comment: '<html>\\r\\n<head>\\r\\n\\t<style type=\\\"text/css\\\">\\r\\n\\t\\t.c0 { font-family:'Arial';font-size:10.5pt; }\\r\\n\\t\\t.c1 { margin-left:0pt;margin-top:0pt;margin-right:0pt;margin-bottom:7.5pt; }\\r\\n\\t</style>\\r\\n</head>\\r\\n<body class=\\\"c0\\\">\\r\\n<p class=\\\"c1\\\">Hi Boris, </p>\\r\\n<p class=\\\"c1\\\">Testing Web 'Portal</p>\\r\\n<p class=\\\"c1\\\">--Jerry</p>\\r\\n<p class=\\\"c1\\\"></p>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n\

Comment: Gets above response and when I put this in string variable gives error "Newline in constant"

Comment: Have you tried removing the \r, \n and \t characters altogether?  At least try it as a test to see if it's the \"s that are causing the problem

Comment: i think that the problem was that `{` was not escaped (it is a char used by Json). bur still, replacing string is very Nasty solution that is why I proposed solution with settings to JsonConvert

Comment: Those curlies are inside a string. They shouldn't need to be escaped.